# Api vs Bing.Com Results

Tags: bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I was wondering if there is a way to access the little gray content boxes located right under a WebPage url in a Bing.com search result with the Big Websearch Api. I referred to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760794.aspx) but nothing in the webpage object maps to what I see in bing.com search results. Any idea how I can access this content through api?

[image: captured from Bing.com search results for Microsoft]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this content is not accessible through the API.  You can suggest this feature is implemented on their feedback forum.
https://cognitive.uservoice.com/